# Nested objects and validates_presence_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested object that is a type of User (say Sub).  I had assumed when saving Sub the User validations would be run as well, but apparently not?  How would I run all validations in User when creating Sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validations do run from the inherited model.

Here's a test case showing that it works.

Test case migration:

```
class CreateUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column :name,:string
      t.column :email, :string
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Test Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Sub < User
  validates_presence_of :email
end
```

Tests Cases:

Creating a sub without either a name or email, save should fail with name,email can't be blank

```
>> b = Sub.create()
=> #<Sub id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> b.save
=> false
>> b.errors
=> #<ActiveRecord::Errors:0x2457458 @errors={"name"=>["can't be blank"], "email"=>["can't be blank"]}, @base=#<Sub id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>>
```

Creating a sub with no email, save should fail with email can't be blank.

```
>> b = Sub.create(:name=>'test')
=> #<Sub id: nil, name: "test", email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> b.save
=> false
>> b.errors
=> #<ActiveRecord::Errors:0x243865c @errors={"email"=>["can't be blank"]}, @base=#<Sub id: nil, name: "test", email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>>
```

Creating a sub with no name, save should fail with name can't be blank.

```
>> b = Sub.create(:email=>'test')
=> #<Sub id: nil, name: nil, email: "test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> b.save
=> false
>> b.errors
=> #<ActiveRecord::Errors:0x2429594 @errors={"name"=>["can't be blank"]}, @base=#<Sub id: nil, name: nil, email: "test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>>
```

Creating a sub with name and email, save should succeed.

```
>> b = Sub.create(:email=>'test',:name=>'test')
=> #<Sub id: 4, name: "test", email: "test", created_at: "2009-10-15 22:27:53", updated_at: "2009-10-15 22:27:53">
>> b.save
=> true
```

Comment: Oops.  I meant I have Sub < User, not Sub belongs_to User.  Guess I didn't mean nested but rather subclass.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do both classes correspond to the same sql table or different tables? Can you post a brief example/test case?